# Como atribuir um valor após uma seleção no section - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

eu gostaria de saber como posso atribuir valores aos selects de meu código, por exemplo se pessoa selecionar ***"de R$ 25.000/mês até R$ 50.000/mês"*** seja gerado um valor no código Javascript equivalente a **50**, pois quero pegar esse valor para realizar um calculo no final.

Um exemplo de algo parecido com o que quero fazer é mostrado no GIF, onde variando o valor do `<input>` é alterado o valor total também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código é este atualmente:

HTML

```js
var faturamento_anual = document.getElementById('faturamento')
     var faturamento_selecionado = ""
     if (faturamento_anual[1].checked) {
        faturamento_selecionado = '50'
     } else if (faturamento_anual[2].checked) {
      faturamento_selecionado = '150'
     }
```

```html
<select name="faturamento" id="faturamento">    
                        <option value="cinco_mil"><li>Até R$ 5.000/mês</li></option>
                        <option value="dez_mil">de R$ 5.000/mês até R$ 10.000/mês</option>
                        <option value="vinte_mil">de R$ 10.000/mês até R$ 25.000/mês</option>
                        <option value="cinquenta_mil">de R$ 25.000/mês até R$ 50.000/mês</option>
                        <option value="cem_mil">de R$ 50.000/mês até R$ 100.000/mês</option>
                        <option value="mill_mil">mais de R$ 100.000/mês</option>
                </select>
```

E no JavaScript eu tentei mas deu erro em todo sistema de calculo.

Comment: Coloca o javascript que está tentando...

Comment: Primeiramente, bem vindo. Olha, vc terá que realizar um evento change nesse seu select. E também poderá atribuir os valores aos values dos respectivos options. Quando vc realizar o evento change, então vc poderá pegar o valor selecionado, fazendo um document.getElementById e pegando o valor do select e atribuí-lo a uma variável, por exemplo.

Comment: O atributo que indica se uma option foi selecionada ou não é `selected` não `checked`.

Answer (score 2):

Olá,

Você precisa escutar o evento de alteração no valor do select.

Tente algo assim no javascript:

```
document.getElementById("faturamento").addEventListener('change', function(){

    let valores = new Array();
    valores['cinco_mil'] = 5;
    valores['dez_mil'] = 10;
    valores['vinte_mil'] = 20;
    valores['cinquenta_mil'] = 50;
    valores['cem_mil'] = 100;
    valores['mill_mil'] = 1000;
    let valorSelecionado = this.value;
    alert(valores[valorSelecionado]);
})
```

Lembre-se que você pode colocar direto os valores numéricos no HTML:

```
...
<option value="5">Até R$ 5.000/mês</option>
...
```

E utilizar mais facilmente no Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("faturamento").addEventListener('change', function(){
    alert(this.value);
})
```

Comment: Obrigado usei o método de usar o valor direto no hrml e deu certo, obrigado <3 Estou muito feliz com o resultado! ^-^

Comment: Olá. É uma ótima notícia que tenha dado certo. Peço que marque a resposta como aceita, assim, ajudamos outras pessoas com dúvidas semelhantes.